# Is it possible to make a ±3.3 power supply from 9V battery?

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, audio, negative-voltage

I am trying to make a little audio amplifier with a ±3.3V power supply I and would like to power it with a 9V battery.
Is there a solution to this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAdMDo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What audio amp IC or circuit is it?

Comment: It is possible and there are many solutions. But the question is why drop the useful battery voltage when you can utilize the full 9V battery voltage, and divide that into +/- 4.5V supplies for op-amps etc. So can you give any more details why it needs to be +/- 3.3V only, so we know what is the best way to make it, or not even needed?

Comment: I am trying to adapt a preamplifier from the book "Small Signal Audio Design" by Douglas Self to make it work as an instrument to headphone amplifier. 

+/- 4.5V is fine too, how I could get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much current you need, and how well balanced the load is there are several solutions.

The easiest to implement is probably using TI's [TLE2426](http://www.ti.com/product/TLE2426) 'rail splitter' which will give you a +/- and a virtual ground. If the output current from this is insufficient it can be buffered with something such as a BUF634 (eye wateringly expensive) or a discrete stage.

Comment: 9V batteries don't have much in the way of current capacity anyway.

Comment: Very true @hobbs